# Is there a way to have the text size fill the entire div after changing the writing-mode to sideways?

Tags: html, css

I have rotated some text in a div using writing-mode: sideways-lr; but after that I want the text to fill the div entirely, while also being scaling up/down depending on how the div stretches.
I'm not familiar with JS but from what little searched, I havent found a solution there either.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main2.css">
        <title>Cyberfin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>Navbar</nav>
            <main>Main</main>
            <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
            <div id="content1">Content1</div>
            <div id="content2">Content2</div>
            <div id="content3">Content3</div>
            <footer>Footer</footer>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS: sidebar contains the rotated text**

```
:root {
    --main-radius: 5px;
    --main-padding: 5px;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  }
  
  .container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.5fr 1.2fr 0.8fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav nav nav nav"
      "sidebar main main main"
      "sidebar content1 content2 content3"
      "sidebar footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 0.2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #242424;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  nav {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: nav;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  main {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: main;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  #sidebar {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: sidebar;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
    writing-mode: sideways-lr;
  }
  
  #content1 {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: content1;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  #content2 {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: content2;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  #content3 {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: content3;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  footer {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    grid-area: footer;
    border-radius: var(--main-radius);
    padding-top: var(--main-padding);
  }
  
  a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
```

I've found ways to make the text larger but it either exceeds the size of the div at full resolution or starts to overflow once I make the window smaller.

I saw that `height: 100%;`, `width: 100%;` and `object-fit: cover;` might help but it looks like it only works for images and not text..?

I'm just looking to have it fill the div regardless of size.
Crude drawings for example/explanation:
[Crude1](https://i.imgur.com/jXRmRjO.png)
[Crude2](https://i.imgur.com/rhB9BPP.png)